# Property 'div' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

i joined a VueJS + nuxt.js project and my vscode detect the whole DOM als error.

Did anyone know how to solve these problem?

```
Property 'div' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a typescript error. Do you use TS? If not, you can probably just disable those errors.

Comment: This is most likely specific to IDE, not anything else, so it's incorrect to ask the question in general.

Comment: Please share your tsconfig.json file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim there is no tsconfig.json in the project.